# How to use regexp with replace query for MYSQL 5.6 version?

Tags: html, mysql

I have to modify a column content using `REGEXP`. I have a html content with some code in 'pre' tags. 
Example:
I have a code like this.

```
    TextText
<span style="font-weight:600">Text one</span>
<pre>
<span style="font-weight:400">text two</span>
</pre>Text Text.
```

Here, I want to delete 'span' tags between the 'pre' tags dynamically using mysql update query.How to use `REGEXP` with `REPLACE` function in MYSQL?

Comment: It would be helpful for others if you explain your problem in more details.

Comment: I have modified the content. Please check once and provide me a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The difficult part of the above problem statement is to actually find the string between `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags. If we are able to find it, we can simply replace it with `''`.

To find that portion of the string in your sample data string, use below query.

```
select substring_index(reverse(substring_index(reverse('TextText <span style="font-weight:600">Text one</span><pre><span style="font-weight:400">text two</span></pre>Text Text.'), reverse('<pre>'), 1)) , '</pre>', 1);
```

Now, the update query becomes something like this.

```
update some_table set some_column = replace(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(reverse(some_column), reverse('<pre>'), 1)) , '</pre>', 1), '');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I'll try